# convert "ls -l" output to an object similar to File

Tags: ruby

I started using Ruby recently and wondering if there is a way to convert a list output to an object so that I can access the attributes.

To be a little bit more clear, here's my output

```
find ./* -type f | xargs ls -l
-rw-r--r--  1 ncktrnl  staff  0 Sep  4 18:52 ./dir1/file3
-rw-r--r--  1 ncktrnl  staff  0 Sep  4 18:52 ./file1
-rw-r--r--  1 ncktrnl  staff  0 Sep  4 18:52 ./file2
```

Now I want to convert the above listing to a File or Dir object so that I can easily access the attributes.

For example:

```
output = `find ./* -type f | xargs ls -l`
out_arr = output.split("\n")
out_arr.each do |line|
  f = File.new(line)
  puts "#{f.mtime}" # => prints mtime after parsing the line
end
```

I am using `File.new` as an example, but I don't think that is how it works, so I wanted to know if there is a way to do this. I can write my own parser but not sure if there is something that already exists. I cannot create a file object of the actual file because I am getting the list by running a remote ssh command on a different host.

Comment: Which parts of the `ls -l` output do you need and what is the specific OS on the remote system? I'm guessing Linux with GNU `ls`.

Comment: Pretty much all parts. File name, permissions, size, mtime.

Comment: `ls -l --time-style=full-iso` produces fixed width columns with easy to parse timestamps so you could pull it apart pretty easily with [`String#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-5B-5D). I'd demonstrate but I have to go so I'll leave it for someone else.

Comment: I was thinking of creating an openstruct for each line and then parse and put in the values myself. However, just being lazy so wanted to know if something like this already exists.

Comment: Great question, I'm needing this for `Net::FTP` as well, since `ftp.mtime(one_file)` is very inefficient for selecting all files in a date range.

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious way to do this is to use [pathname](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/index.html) or [find](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/find/rdoc/index.html) from std-lib to handle this.  Using the `each_child` method, or something like that, along with whatever filtering, you can do this without needing to shell out to an external command at all.

You can also do the same without touching std-lib, using `File` and `Dir` objects.

You can't create a File object with the details you want, trivially, although you could extract the path (only) and create file instances by hand.  Really, though, avoiding the external shell command entirely is the best bet.

Comment: Daniel, The situation is that I am using Net::SSH to run the command on a remote host. Once I get the output, I want to convert it into a structure that I can use easily. If the files were on the host I am running my script on then I can use the File or Dir objects. However that won't work with remote ssh commands.

Answer (score 0):

There is the [net-ftp-list](http://rubygems.org/gems/net-ftp-list) gem, which can parse ls output from different remote systems.